# Neural network architecture recomendation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

Its my first time working with neural networks and I have been given the task of predicting some values of a dataset and I could make good use of some help on deciding which is the smartest architecture for the task. I'm working with Keras using Tensorflow as backend.

I'm not going into details but basically I have performed lots of CFD simulations on similar but slightly different geometries to obtain a stress value on the surface of the geometries. All the geometries have the same conectivity and number of nodes and I have the stress value for each of those nodes.

Simply put, I have an input matrix of [2500,3,300] where 2500 is the amount of nodes in each geometry, 3 represents the x,y,z coordinates in space of each node on the mesh and 300 is the total number of geometries I have. For the stress I have an output matrix of [2500,300] where 2500 is the value of stress for each node and 300 once again corresponds to the number of instances. I would like to train some kind of neural network so I can predict the stress values given the geometry.

I have been basing my architecture on the following paper but I can't not make use of the part in which the convolutional networks are employed. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5805990/

The simplest approach I can think of is a fully connected network but I struggle to figure out the layer architecture to relate the 3D matrix of the geometry to the 2D of the output stress matrix with my scarce knowledge of the subject.

Any suggestiong is more than welcomed. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: This is too broad as it is posed. You should try to search for research papers that have tried to tackle similar problems to take inspiration for your approach. Here are some references that may or may not be useful: [Geometric Deep Learning](http://geometricdeeplearning.com/)

Comment: Also, another reference I came across recently, an upcoming Siggraph '19 paper about using neural networks for automatic 3D mesh skinning: [NeuroSkinning: Automatic Skin Binding for Production Characters with Deep Graph Networks](http://kunzhou.net/2019/neuroskin.pdf). You _might_ be able to use some of the ideas there, since there is some similarity in the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- Since I have been working with stress values prediction using DL, I would like to recommend you to work with **CNN** models which you have filters due to intelligent learning capacity even correlation between parameters your suppose to following. Nevertheless **RNN** and its promised version like **LSTM** & **GRU** have good performance on sufficient data if you have.  Unfortunately I can't address you to paper because that this issue is still under study!
- Another point I can turn out is reshape of your data is kind of important when you feed to NN models especially when you are dealing with **time-series** data.